# This program is to distinguish the input value is correct

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatchesMethodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String s;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input one real number to one decimal place and one natural number(ex. 1.4 5): ");
        s = input.next();

        if (s.matches("\\f{1} \\d{1}$"))
            System.out.print("You input correctly.");
        else
            System.out.print("You input incorrectly.");
    }
}
```

The user should input one real number to one decimal place and one natural number. The program prints whether user inputs correctly or not. So when I input 1.4 and 5, I want the program to print "You input correctly", but it outputs "You input incorrectly" instead. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you paste the code and output instead of a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular expression, `\f` doesn't match a floating point number, as you seem to want it to do - it matches a special kind of character called the "form-feed character."

Try changing your regular expression match to:

```
s.matches("\\d{1}\\.\\d{1} \\d{1}$")
```

This checks for a single digit, a period, a digit, a space, and a final digit. (Note that your "natural number" is limited to one digit by the `{1}` term.)

**Edit:** You may also need to change `input.next()` to `input.nextLine()`, since the `.next()` method may only grab the first integer. Untested.

Answer (score 1):

The `matches` mathod takes a regular expression. If you put `\f` you're asking it to match a form feed character.

Here's a reference: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/40regular_expressions/25sum-regex.html